Is there a way to use Python connector for postgresql with alloydb Auth Proxy?
I'm able to run a query against an AlloyDB instance using AlloyDB auth proxy and python code(using SQLAlchemy library).
But I want to test the IAM authentication for AlloyDB and Python connector for PostgreSQL library but I don't see an option to use the IP address 127.0.0.1 that is the one opened by the proxy.
Do you know if there is a way to do this?
Thanks!

If you're using the Python Connector, there's no need (or way) to use the Auth Proxy. The Python Connector will establish a secure connection for you to the AlloyDB instance. In effect, it's a library version of the Auth Proxy.
